# Disconnect from Wifi network under Windows 8?

Tags: networking, windows-8, wireless-networking, connection

I'm working with that cursed operating system known as Windows 8. That's the operating system where Microsoft believes everything is a tablet.

I'm trying to disconnect from a Wifi network. I right click on the Mifi hotspot below, but nothing happens:

[image]

I don't want to "forget" the network because it uses a 24 character password. So its non-trivial to set it up again.

Because its a desktop (and not a tablet), I cannot walk out of range of the base station.

How do I disconnect from a wireless network under Windows 8?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to do this:

1. Go to *Desktop*.
2. Click on the Network icon in the tray: [image: Network icon]
3. On the *Networks* panel, pick one of these to disconnect:
   [image: Networks CPLK]

   a. Turn on *Airplane Mode*.

   b. Turn off *Wi-Fi*.

   c. Select yet another network, and choose whether you will *Connect automatically* in the future.

Any of these choices should still keep the system password after disconnection. See MS on [passwords for automatic logon](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/store-passwords-for-automatic-logon) if there is an issue.